# C# Towers of Hanoi console application.

Tags: c#, .net, windows, console

I'll keep this succinct. I am learning C# and exploring the possibilities of the language. Being a python programmer by heart, I am fairly new to the .NET realm.

I am currently writing a Towers of Hanoi console application. I already understand the recursion part of the code as that is not challenging.

Here is my current code for my peg class.

```
namespace Tower_of_hanoi
{
class PegClass
{
private int pegheight;
private int y = 3;
int[] rings = new int[0];
public PegClass()
{ 
    // default constructor 

}
public PegClass(int height)
{
    pegheight = height;
}




// other functions
public void AddRing(int size)
{
    Array.Resize(ref rings, rings.Length + 1);
    rings[rings.Length - 1] = size;
}

public void DrawPeg(int x)
{ 
    for (int i = 1; i <= pegheight; i++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.WriteLine("|");
        y++;
    }

    if (x < 7)
    {
        x = 7;
    }


    Console.SetCursorPosition(x - 7, y); // print the base
    Console.WriteLine("----------------");
}


}
}
```

And this is my code for the main class to display the pegs. I have facilitated the printing of the pegs by putting them in a method.

```
    namespace Tower_of_hanoi
     {
      class Program
      {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

    PegClass myPeg = new PegClass(8);
    PegClass myPeg2 = new PegClass(8);
    PegClass myPeg3 = new PegClass(8);
    DrawBoard(myPeg, myPeg2, myPeg3);

    Console.ReadLine();                            
}

 public static void DrawBoard(PegClass peg1,PegClass peg2,PegClass peg3)
 {
    Console.Clear();
    peg1.DrawPeg(20);
    peg2.DrawPeg(40);
    peg3.DrawPeg(60);

}

}

}
```

My question remains,

How does one move "rings" over to "pegs" in a console application? I understand how this would work in WinForms, but I want a challenge.

Thank you everyone in advance,

youmeoutside

Comment: What do you mean move "rings to "pegs"?How you draw the rings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do ,is modify the DrawPeg method to accept the number of current "rings"

```
public void DrawPeg(int x, int numberOfRings = 0)
{
        for (int i = pegheight; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            string halfRing = new string(' ', i);
            if (numberOfRings > 0)
            {
                if (i <= numberOfRings)
                    halfRing = new string('-', numberOfRings - i + 1);

            }

            Console.SetCursorPosition(x - halfRing.Length * 2 + i + (halfRing.Contains("-") ? (-i + halfRing.Length) : 0), y);
            Console.WriteLine(halfRing + "|" + halfRing);
            y++;
        }

        if (x < 7)
        {
            x = 7;
        }


        Console.SetCursorPosition(x - 7, y); // print the base
        Console.WriteLine("----------------");
}
```

Then ,you can call your DrawBoard method with your current values (Now they are hard-coded)

```
public static void DrawBoard(PegClass peg1, PegClass peg2, PegClass peg3)
{
        Console.Clear();
        peg1.DrawPeg(20, 1);
        peg2.DrawPeg(40, 2);
        peg3.DrawPeg(60, 4);
}
```

Now all you have to do ,is call the methods with different numbers of rings every time your player makes a move

Comment: My man, I have been searching for a solution like this for a long time. Thank you so much for your solution and your patience! Definitely giving you a reputation bonus!

Comment: You did most of the work...I just modified one method

Comment: Thank you anyway. It was seriously very nice of you to respond to my question.